# Batch file to replace spaces with underscores in folder names

Tags: batch-file

I need a batch file to replace spaces with underscores in folder names (only in folders not  in file names)

Thanks

Comment: Sure... what have you tired yet? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I don't know batch files at all, sorry

Comment: No need to be sorry, it's just that this type of question most likely won't be answered around here. But if you google I'm sure you'll find various solutions for your problem.

Comment: I googled of course and I found some threads, but nothing that meets my requirements. and because it's very simple I hope someone will answer

Comment: If this is for listing folders and files in a certain manner, start by learning how to list contents (see `help for`, don't use `for /f` with `dir /b` please), then figuring out how to distinguish files from folders (hint: check for existence of `foo\NUL`), string replacement for environment variables is detailed in `help set`, as is delayed expansion. If you want to rename them, look at `help for`, specifically `for /d` and above things as well. The thing is, this is trivial for me but I've been doing batch programming for years. But even so, you should at least show some effort.

Comment: Side note: Regardless of what you're after here, both options I interpreted from your question would be a one-liner in PowerShell, so if the batch file requirement isn't a hard one (e.g. on Windows 7 and above) there are better options.

Comment: Found the answer in the below link: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3565

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /R test /D %%d IN (*) DO (
   SET "NAME=%%~d"
   SET "NEWNAME=!NAME: =_!"
   IF NOT "!NAME!"=="!NEWNAME!" @ECHO Rename '!NAME!' to '!NEWNAME!'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I can't comment on the guy before me because I don't have enough reputation.Here is a modified Version that works ^^:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /D %%d IN (*) DO (
   SET "NAME=%%d"
   SET "NEWNAME=!NAME: =_!"
   IF NOT "!NAME!"=="!NEWNAME!" rename "!NAME!" "!NEWNAME!"
)
pause
exit
```